# Unable to open Update manager or Ubuntu tweak

Tags: permissions, update-manager, sudo, ubuntu-tweak

I cannot open Update manager and Ubuntu Tweak

when I open Ubuntu tweak I get this log

```
user@laptop:~$ ubuntu-tweak

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 124, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.main import UbuntuTweakWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.apps import AppsPage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/apps/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from aptsources.sourceslist import SourcesList
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 124, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.main import UbuntuTweakWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ubuntutweak.apps import AppsPage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/apps/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from aptsources.sourceslist import SourcesList
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
```

and when I open update manager I get this

```
user@laptop:~$ update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 37, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .InstallProgress import InstallProgress
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/InstallProgress.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .Core.utils import (inhibit_sleep,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init_config()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 37, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .InstallProgress import InstallProgress
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/InstallProgress.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .Core.utils import (inhibit_sleep,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init_config()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
```

It has been happening after I wiped my entire Ubuntu root and used my previous existing home partition.

There is an icon of update notification which I cannot seem to use because none of the options can be clicked. Further, this icon does not stop showing even after updating from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Both are related to common error.to get out of it ,

open your terminal and type

```
sudo chmod o+r /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude
```

then try again.

and you can also get them accessible by launching them as a root user with sudo command .I mean `sudo <your_application>`

Comment: can you also describe the underlying cause, or what this 'fix' does?

Comment: @david6 sure , those programs should have to run as root but user has launched them as normal user , so now my answer will turn them to accessible for normal user session too.

Comment: okay lemme try and i'll update! yesterday while rebooting  also noticed that when i reboot it logs me out instead of rebooting, same from the login screen stays there!

Comment: Sure.  Let us know.